# Output file text as triangle

Tags: python

Forgive the wild question, but I am new to Python and am having trouble with some loops on a project. I am basically trying to get a list from a txt file printed in a specific order and in a triangle shape.

I am trying to create a code that will take strings on a list and print them in a specified order in a triangle shape. I have started with a code that writes a file with items in it such as:

```
4  jeeps
5  trees
2  dogs
1  I
6  coding
3  love
```

Following this I wrote a script that orders numerically from the first row and then prints the output omitting the number. I then want the output structured as a Floyd's Triangle design. I keep running into errors and I am unsure where I am going wrong and could use some help:

```
def mysort(line):
    return line.split()[0]

with open("message_file.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.readlines()
n = int(len(text))
count = n
for line in sorted(text, key=mysort):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            print(count, end='')
        print (line[3:].strip())
```

The output for where I am currently looks something like this :

```
    I
    6I
    66I
    666I
    6666I
    66666I
    dogs
    6dogs
    66dogs
    666dogs
    6666dogs
    66666dogs
    etc...
```

Whereas I am trying to figure out how to get it to look like this:

```
    I
    dogs love
    jeeps trees coding
```

It is complicated to wrap my head around this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try doing it on paper ;)

Comment: You should consider finding some DSA (Data Structures and Algorythms) content to study in order to learn the common approaches for these types of problems. Udemy has several good courses like this that use Python, and YouTube and the interwebsus have plenty of free content. You probably want to: read file into a dict, add words from the dict in order to make a string, move to the next string when current is longer than previous, add last string to second to last if it ends up being shorter.